# Run openvpn.exe, FreeFileSync.exe, then close command prompt

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, openvpn

I am trying to write a batch file that connects to an OpenVPN profile, runs a FreeFileSync batch file, then exits.

```
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config"
openvpn.exe --config synology.ovpn
"C:\Program Files\FreeFileSync\FreeFileSync.exe" "C:\Users\MrPeanut\Desktop\Sync.ffs_batch"
taskkill /f /im openvpn.exe
exit
```

It connects to my OpenVPN server. However, at this point, I'm still in the OpenVPN program, so the next command (FreeFileSync) can't run.

I know this is very basic, but I can't figure out how to run the next command while my OpenVPN program/connection is active.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenVPN. When you run openvpn.exe from a batch file, are you saying the batch file waits until openvpn.exe exits, before continuing with the next line?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yeah, that's how it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to run it in the background, using `START /B`. This should work:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config"
START "" /B openvpn.exe --config synology.ovpn
"C:\Program Files\FreeFileSync\FreeFileSync.exe" "C:\Users\MrPeanut\Desktop\Sync.ffs_batch"
taskkill /f /im openvpn.exe
exit
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work fine.

Comment: The `/B` option to the `START` command means "don't open a new window".

Comment: You might not need the `/B` switch, just `start` should work fine as well; I suggest to use `start "" [/B] command`, to clearly define a window title (`""`), as otherwise, `start` might interprete the command as title if it is encloded within `""`...

Comment: @aschipfl edited. But also, the `/B` does make things a bit cleaner by not opening up more windows than needed

Comment: `START "" /B openvpn.exe --config synology.ovpn` still starts openvpn.exe in the same command prompt window. I should have mentioned openvpn.exe is running in the command prompt. `START "" /B cmd "openvpn.exe --config mclewis.ovpn"` worked.